# How to create an easing effect on scrolling a site

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, easing

I've looked at loads of the other questions here but none of them are clear or good examples in my opinion. So I'm putting this out there again to see if there are any up to date answers.

This site has a beautiful scroll effect. Where the page eases on a scroll. It's no a 'scroll to' effect its simply on regular scrolling. 
The 'anti-gravity' parallax effect of the images is really great. 
I expect it needs to be a Javascript answer. Help appreciated, Thanks.

https://www.allyourdays.com

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The smooth scroll, for example https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want smooth scrolling when you scroll with mouse / mobile touch / laptop touch pad scrolling.

I think, you can check this might be it's will fix your problem. http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html